# Bash: Tab filename completion on all sub-folders

Tags: bash, command-line, tab-completion

Is there any way to configure bash so that hitting tab to expand filename will search all sub-folders as well as the current folder?

e.g. my folder structure

```
readme.txt
colors/blue.txt
colors/red.txt
people/roger.txt
```

I want `less r<tab>` (or maybe `less **/r<tab>` to expand to show all expansion options beginning with `r`:

`readme.txt colors/red.txt people/roger.txt`

Comment: For just a specific command, or always?

Comment: Always. Wherever "x<tab>" would normally return all files beginning with x in current folder, I'd want it to return all in the folders below too.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible to happen _always_, as it would have to override `compgen -F` behaviour. You could probably get something like it for specific commands with your own completion function, though.

Comment: I'd settle for specific commands certainly. Current use case is running tests that are scatted across subfolders.

Comment: Before trying to solve it with modified tab completion: is anything keeping you from using `shopt -s globstar` and `**/*something*` style globs, or `find -exec` or `find | xargs`, maybe wrapped in little convenience functions?

Comment: Mainly that <tab> lets me type one or two chars and then choose an option. If it's not interactive, it would have to run on all matches.

Comment: Could you add an example of a directory structure and what the completion should return? Relative paths, just filenames...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following situation, including two levels of subdirectories:

```
.
├── colors
│   ├── blue.txt
│   └── red.txt
├── completion.bash
├── people
│   ├── rdir
│   ├── roger.txt
│   └── subdir
│       └── rhino.txt
└── readme.txt
```

You can get the kind of completion you want with this function:

```
_comp_less () {
    # Store current globstar setting and set globstar if necessary
    local glob_flag
    if shopt -q globstar; then
        glob_flag=0
    else
        glob_flag=1
        shopt -s globstar
    fi

    # $2 is the word being completed
    local cur=$2

    # Loop over all files and directories in the current and all subdirectories
    local fname
    for fname in **/"$cur"*; do

        # Only add files
        if [[ -f "$fname" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY+=("$fname")
        fi
    done

    # Set globstar back to previous value if necessary
    if (( glob_flag == 1 )); then
        shopt -u globstar
    fi

    return 0
}
```

It checks for the `globstar` shell option and sets it if necessary (and unsets it again if it wasn't set to start with), then uses the `**/"$cur"*` glob to get all files and directories (including subdirectories) that complete the current word, and finally filters out directory names.

The function can go in your `.bashrc`, together with the instruction to use it for `less`:

```
complete -F _comp_less less
```

Now, `less r<tab>` completes as follows:

```
$ less r
colors/red.txt           people/subdir/rhino.txt
people/roger.txt         readme.txt
```